# Foundation throwing error in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, zurb-foundation

i am using foundation for the first time its throwing error some inavlid word u 
can see that in the image file i am attaching I dont know whats happening here 
.this is my webpack config file i am setting the entry point.
I am also setting externals and plugins but still it is not working.
i have installed this dependencies  css-loader@0.23.1 script-loader@0.6.1 style-loader@0.13.0 jquery@2.2.1 foundation-sites@6.2.0.

webpack.config.js -

```
 var webpack = require('webpack');

 module.exports = {
  entry:[
    'script!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'script!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js',
    './app/app.jsx'
],
externals:{
    jquery: 'jQuery'
},
plugins : [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '$' : 'jquery',
        'jQuery' : 'jquery'
    })

],
output:{
    path:__dirname,
    filename:'./public/bundle.js',
},
resolve:{
    root:__dirname,
    alias:{
        Main:'app/components/Main.jsx',
        Nav: 'app/components/Nav.jsx',
        Weather : 'app/components/Weather.jsx',
        WeatherForm : 'app/components/WeatherForm.jsx',
        WeatherMessage : 'app/components/WeatherMessage.jsx',
        About : 'app/components/About.jsx',
        Examples: 'app/components/Examples.jsx',
        openWeatherMap : 'app/api/openWeatherMap.jsx'
    },
    extensions:['','.js','.jsx']
},
module:{
    loaders:[
        {
            loader:'babel-loader',
            query:{
                presets:['react','es2015']
            },
            test:/\.jsx?$/,
            exclude:/(node_modules|bower_components)/
        }
    ]
},
devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
}
```

app.jsx : -

```
   var React = require('react');
   var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
   var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router');
   var Main = require('Main');
   var Weather = require('Weather');
   var About = require('About');
   var Examples = require('Examples')


   //load foundation
      require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js');
      $(document).foundation();

    ReactDOM.render(
   <Router history={hashHistory}>
   <Route path="/" component={Main}>
   <Route path="about" component={About}/>
   <Route path="examples" component={Examples}/>
     <IndexRoute component={Weather}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to apply `css-loader` to a JavaScript file.

```
require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.js');
//                                                      ^^
```

`css-loader` expects CSS and JavaScript is clearly not valid CSS, therefore it fails to parse. Assuming that you just want to use the CSS, you need to import `dist/foundation.min.css`.

```
require('style!css!foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css');
```

On a side note, it's generally discouraged to use inline loaders and you should define a rule for `.css` files instead.